# Date Comparing in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, date

i'm currently working on a little project and i'm stuck with a little problem.
I would like my program to call a method `CheckDate` on boot.
This method would read in a *.txt* file to see the last saved date in **(yyyy/mm/dd)** format.
Then it would compare it with todays date and if it's not the same go on with some instructions.I've read the doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) but can't quite find which method best suites my need.

Question 1: Is there a way to get today's date in **(yyyy/mm/dd)** format?

Question 2: What's the easiest way to compare Dates in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you currently read in the string?  You'll want to parse it into a `DateTime` object and compare that with `DateTime.Today`.  Don't try to turn `DateTime.Today` into a string and do the compare that way.  The `DateTime` object has lots of logic built in for date/time functionality so you don't need to re-invent it.

Comment: I currently read it Line by Line in my.txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get today's date as a string by simply formatting a date.

```
String today = String.Format("{0: yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now); 
String today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

I would advise against using a text file as your means of saving data but if you are going with that system the only thing you would have to do is check to see if the date from the text file matches the date you formatted.  Simply comparing formatted strings should do the trick.

if (string a == string b)

You could even put it in one line without having to format stuff separately

```
if (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Equals("date pulled from txt file"))
```

Comment: On my system, that gives 2011-12-15. While I think they should use that format in such a context anyway, they shouldn't get it due to changes in system settings. You want to escape to `@"yyyy\/MM\/dd"` to guarantee `/` rather than whatever is the systems date-separator.

Comment: @JonHanna It shouldn't matter as long as you parse both dates the same way.

Comment: @Chase That's precisely the problem. For a long time, this machine would have written and parsed your string in the format "2011/12/16" because with the default set to be dd/MM/yyyy then `/` gets turned to `/`. I changed that because I prefer standard format so now it would take your format string to produce 2011-12-16. If this program was running on it, it would have broken.

Comment: If you parse both dates every time there will be no conflict.

Answer (score 7):

```
1. DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
2. DateTime.Parse(input).Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(input).Date` - There's a runtime error waiting to happen :)

Comment: He said easiest way, he didn't say anything about validation :D.  Plus it isn't a huge leap to find TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the easiest way to compare Dates in C#?

Store them not as text but in a DatteTime.

Compare the variables.

If there is a time in both, compare a.Date == b.Date.

> Is there a way to get today's date in (yyyy/mm/dd) format?

Yes. This is wrong, though. PARSE The wrong input and compare the parsed data.

Comment: How do you store a `DateTime` as a `DateTime` in a `.txt` file, as the OP asked?

Comment: Ok but i'm kind of new to this.
If i'm not mistaken streamwriter and streamreader are working with strings no? That's why I was stuck with the convert to string part.
How could I store datetime in my .txt file?

Comment: @KirkWoll Exactly how I should have asked it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `DateTime.Compare` method that you could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx - this should also let you use the built-in < and > operators.

Answer (score 1):

By the letter of the question:

1:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd")
```

2:

```
if(d1 < d2)...
if(d2 >= d1)...
```

etc.

However.

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(readInString, "yyyy-MM-dd", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt))
{
  if(dt != DateTime.Now.Date)
  {
    //Code for case where it's no longer that day goes here.
  }
}
else
{
  //Code for someone messed up the file and it's not a valid date any more goes here.
}
```

1. You're doing this for computer-reading, not human-reading, so use the standard format rather than the conventional format (standard as in ISO, but also every country except North Korea has it as the national standard): yyyy-MM-dd (Edit: I see you're in Canada, CSA Z234.5:1989 is the relevant national standard on date-times for technical purposes; it says to use yyyy-MM-dd).
2. You should do it the other way around, read the string, parse the date, and do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at the [FileInfo-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) ... you can compare the LastWriteTime Member to DateTime.Today

Answer (score 0):

//use a TimeSpan  do something like this

```
  strCurDate = string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy/mm/dd");
  FileInfo fiUpdateFileFile = null;
  fiUpdateFileFile = new FileInfo(YourFile Location + Your FileName);
  if (((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - fiUpdateFileFile.LastWriteTime)).TotalHours < 24)
  {  
    // do your logic here...
  }
// you could also get at DateTime.Now.Date() or Day.. depending on what you want to do
```

Comment: Ok but since I'll have to write in that file in the //Do logic part, 
How will I write the new date?Or Maybe writting anything int will change the `LastWriteTime`??

Comment: Except it doesn't work. The idea of looking at the last file write time is nice, but strCurDate is wrong (on my system running it right now gives the result "YYYY-12-DD"), and isn't used anyway. Also, "last updated before today" (in the question) is different to updated in the last 24hours give or take a daylight savings change (in your answer).

Comment: Thanks @Jon i'll go with the other logic

Comment: you can always use the DateTime.Now to write depends on where in the process you want to write.. if the file is opened you would close it and create the FileInfo object at that time capturing the LastWriteTime and storing it in a string variable .. but if you have to write it to a file .. add the DateTime.Now right before you close the file.. make sense..? for the format use lowercase yyyymmdd

Comment: I actually prefer this approach in general. `yyyymmdd` is going to be the year, followed by the minutes, followed by the day though.

Comment: _compare it with todays date and if it's not the same_ is not the same as _not in the last 24 hours_.  Last Saved Date could have been done at 11 PM and the next run could be just an hour later _and_ at a new date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = d1.AddMilliseconds(123456789);
string formattedDate = d1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

TimeSpan ts = d2 - d1;

double dayDiff = ts.TotalDays;
double hourDiff = ts.TotalHours;
double minuteDiff = ts.TotalMinutes;
double secondDiff = ts.TotalSeconds;
double milDiff = ts.TotalMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine("Formatted Date: {0}\r\nDate Diff:\r\nTotal Days: {1}; Total Hours: {2}; Total Minutes: {3}; Total Seconds: {4}; Total Milliseconds: {5}", formattedDate,dayDiff,hourDiff,minuteDiff,secondDiff,milDiff);
```

**Output:**

Formatted Date: 2011/12/15

Date Diff:
Total Days: 1.42889802083333; Total Hours: 34.2935525; Total Minutes: 2057.61315; Total Seconds:
123456.789; Total Milliseconds: 123456789

**Edited my initial post to clarify how the "Total" properties work.*

Comment: That will work as well but look into the TotalHours property it gets down to the true hours / total hours in a day when comparing it to current DateTime or when using a TimeStamp to do d2 - d1 in your example.