# How can I compare Two Dates using C#?

Tags: c#

How can I compare Two Dates using C# where one is in my database file and other will be given through a textbox and the date formate is yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+compare+dates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=yMImU7CdBO3a8geA0IBA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date Comparing in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524283/date-comparing-in-c-sharp)

Comment: BTW date should not be in a Textbox. Instead use a DateTime Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string date = "2014-03-17";
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(date);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.Date;
if (d1.Equals(d2))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt1= DateTime.ParseExact("Yourdate1","yyyy-MM-dd",
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2= DateTime.ParseExact("Yourdate2","yyyy-MM-dd",
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int result = DateTime.Compare(dt1,dt2) ;
if(result == 0)
{
 //both dates are same    
}
else if(result < 0)
{
 //Date1 is lessthan Date2
}
else 
{
//Date2 is lessthan Date1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(datetime1 == DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateTime.Text,"yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
       //Code
    }
```

**OR**

```
if(datetime1 == Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateTime.Text))
{
   //Code
}
```